# Determine a curves position over another curve

Tags: calculus, functions

if the curve of $y= mx^2 -2mx +m$ is over rhe curve of $y=2x^2 -3$, then the limits of the interval must be

my attempt: I dont know which concept i have to use. I only know that discriminant is use to check if the curve (parabola)intercept or touch the x axis.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let the first function be $Y$ and the second function be denoted as $y$. We are required to find the values of m for which $Y>y$. This implies $$mx^2−2mx+m>2x^2-3$$ or $$(m-2)x^2+x(-2m)+m+3>0$$. This functions will be always positive if the discriminant is negative or if the above function is always above the x-axis (having no real solutions). The inequality involving the discrimant will be in temrs of $m$ and will give you the desired interval.

Comment: how do you know it will be always positive? since we havent yet know the m . Or maybe you think its definitelny Y over y if Y's determinant is smaller than zero?

Comment: What will be always positive? The inequality set up is derived from the statement of the problem you have posed. If you are unsure as to how would negative discriminant always lead to a positive quadratic, I think that you should review your course material again...

Comment: does over means the result or it means that the Y is on the top of y (sorry, im indonesian. im not really good at english)

Comment: Y is on top of y. I think this could have caused you some confusion....